# Unable to pull eBay orders, got an EPROTO error

Tags: openssl, ebay-api

Last week we're getting an EPROTO error on all eBay integrations. I'm not sure if it has to do with eBay *transitioning from DigiCert to Sectigo*. And not sure how to fix this, I thought this is just a notice saying that they're be using Sectigo to authenticate their SSL certificate.

```
Error: write EPROTO 139788329363328:error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 70
    
        at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:16) {
      errno: -71,
      code: 'EPROTO',
      syscall: 'write'
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The package I'm using uses request, so I had to manually modify the request option to force all requests to eBay to make use of TLSv1.2

```
agentOptions:{
  //force request to make use of 1.2 and above
  minVersion: 'TLSv1.2'
}
```